# OrientDB prevent EDGE creation when in_ is part of CONTENT JSON

Tags: json, orientdb

When I create a record using the CONTENT form of the command, any entries which start with in_ get created as edges. How do I prevent that?

Example:

```
CREATE CLASS Test EXTENDS V;
CREATE VERTEX Test CONTENT { "key": "val", "in_foo": "bar" };
SELECT FROM Test;
```

Result:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#13:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Test",
            "key": "val",
            "in_foo": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed  in 0.069 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

When viewing things in Studio, that "in_foo" appears to be an EDGE (Shows up via an IN column, not as a regular property).

I'm trying to do this in schema-less form, but even if I add in_foo as a property, it still seems to be an EDGE.

Am I missing something or how do I prevent this from happening and allow for properties to start with "in_"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field **in_foo** is correctly created as string but Studio wrongly group it as edge. I've opened an issue, should be fixed in the next release.

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues/332

Comment: Thanks. That was my ultimate conclusion too after looking at a few more things (actual edges represented in the results).